# Unwrap multiple optionals in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alert, option-type, optional-parameters

I'm working on a Swift project now, and I'm learning the language while developing an app. I'm trying to make a function to invoke an "Alert popup" and have a question for optional unwrapping.

```
func showAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actions: [UIAlertAction], style: UIAlertController.Style) {
    let title = title ?? nil
    let message = message ?? nil

    print("alert \(title), \(message),") // get optional value or nil, not String and nil...
        
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
    actions.forEach { alert.addAction($0)}
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Since I need to show several alert popups in the app, I created a custom function "showAlert" and I want to call this function like the code below.

```
showAlert(title: "delete", message: nil, actions: [deleteAction], style: .alert)
```

The problem is the title and message value can be a String or nil (like... Alert controller only displays a title but message), so I need to clarify if the title and message contain a value or not.

What I want to do here is, check the title and message value, and apply String or nil into this part, `let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)`.
I read some of the articles for optional binding, but if I write this code using it,

```
func showAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actions: [UIAlertAction], style: UIAlertController.Style) {

    if let title = title, let message = message {
        print("alert \(title), \(message),") // get optional value
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
        actions.forEach { alert.addAction($0)}
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I can only handle the situation where title is String and message is String.
I also want to care the situations like title is nil but message is String, or title is String and message is nil.

So how can I write code that takes either String or nil in the showAlert's title and message, and apply either String or nil in this part, `UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)`?

Comment: Just found out that the UI alert controller takes optional values to both title and message, so probably I don't need to unwrap this...
UIAlertController(title: String?, message: String?, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. [`UIAlertController.init(title:message:preferredStyle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620092-init) has following signature.

```
convenience init(title: String?, 
         message: String?, 
  preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style)
```

Both `title` & `message` are already `String?` types, so you can pass whatever you receive in the function arguments without checking anything for optionals like you are doing in your first version.

```
func showAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actions: [UIAlertAction], style: UIAlertController.Style) {
    // Notice how the redundant declarations in your version have been removed
    print("alert \(title), \(message),") // get optional value or nil, not String and nil...
        
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
    actions.forEach { alert.addAction($0)}
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, I just saw the auto-completion tells me that it takes optional values... But thank you for your help and clear explanation!